# Accessing dynamic view within ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I have the following method to create this `ExpandoObject`:

```
List<object> example = new List<object>();
foreach (var rate in rates)
{
    var rateObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    rateObject["Id"] = rate.Id;
    rateObject["RateType"] = rate.RateType;
    rateObject["Units"] = rate.R6Item.Unit.Symbol;
    rateObject["Schedule"] = rate.R6Item.Schedule.Description;
    rateObject["R6Code"] = rate.R6Item.Code;
    rateObject["R6Description"] = rate.R6Item.Description;
    rateObject["R7Code"] = rate.R7Item.Code;
    rateObject["R7Description"] = rate.R7Item.Description;
    rateObject["DICODE"] = rate.R6Item.Schedule.Discipline.Code;

    foreach (var currency in rate.Project.ProjectCurrencies)
    {
        rateObject[currency.Currency.Name] = currency.Currency.Name;
    }

    example.Add(rateObject);
}
```

Now when I expand the example object it looks like so:

[image]

and if I expand further it's like so:

[image]

Now how I want the data is how it's displayed inside the Dynamic View, is there a way to be able to access this? and have example just equal to the Dynamic View of the `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question? I don't understand what you want. Wild guess: do you want to see added items of `ExpandoObject` as normal properties when inspecting it during debugging?

Comment: yes that's essentially it, apologies for it not being clear, it's just so when I hover over it, it doesn't just say {system.dynamic.expandoobject}

Comment: What should it say? What do you expect to see instead of type?

Comment: sorry don't think I'm explaining myself well here, just need to be able to access the data within the expando object

Comment: Check for *debugger visualizers*. There are few standard ones, to display formatted json or xaml, perhaps you want that?

Comment: Check [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-managed-objects).

Comment: The **Dynamic view** should display all keys/values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surely do a lot to enhance your debugging experience. Here is my quick attempt:

[image: Preview]

I had to use composition to extend sealed class `ExpandoObject` with attributes:

```
class MyExpando
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public ExpandoObject Value { get; } = new();

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, object?>> Properties => Value.ToList();

    public void Add(string key, object value) => ((IDictionary<string, object?>)Value)[key] = value;

    public override string ToString() => string.Join(", ", Value.Select(o => $"{o.Key}={o.Value}"));
}
```

There are:

- overriden `ToString()` method used when displaying collections,
- hidden in debugger property `Value` to access `ExpandoObject`,
- property `Properties` used to visualize in debugger `KeyValuePair` entries.